# Calculating the reading on ammeter \$A_1\$: why am I incorrect?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current, ohms-law

I have the following circuit:

> The voltmeter \$V_1\$ measures the voltage drop across the \$9.00 \ \Omega\$ resistor and has a reading of \$4.50 \ \text{V}\$.
> [image]

I am trying to calculate the reading on ammeter \$A_1\$. I used Ohm's law to calculate \$I = \dfrac{6.0 \ \text{V}}{9.0 \ \Omega}\$, but I am told that it is actually \$I = \dfrac{4.5 \ \text{V}}{9.0 \ \Omega} = 0.50 \ \text{A} \$. Why am I incorrect, and why is it actually \$I = \dfrac{4.5 \ \text{V}}{9.0 \ \Omega}\$?

Comment: Why do you think it should be \$\frac{6V}{9\Omega}\$?

Comment: The magnitude of amps through the resistor times the resistor value must be the voltage drop across the resistor. That is Ohm's Law. You know the value of the resistor and you know the voltage drop across the resistor. So you solve for what is left. And the ammeter must measure this current. Yes?

Comment: @jonk Yes – I forgot that Ohm's law is the voltage drop across the resistor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohm's law states U=R*I  (or I=U/R).
Where you got it wrong is on which "U" (ie which voltage) is the one to use.

The voltage U is the voltage drop across the resistor R (through which flows a current I).

So if you consider the 9 ohms resistor, then you must consider the voltage drop across the 9 ohms resistor, ie V1.

Or if you want to consider the whole 6V (ie the 6V voltage drop), then you would need to consider the full resistance across it, ie the "virtual" resistor equivalent to the 3 other resistors connected together(9ohms in series with {R // 4 ohms} ).