# Finding resistance for parallel resistors: how is my reasoning incorrect, and what is the correct reasoning?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, resistance, ohms-law

I have the following circuit:

> The voltmeter \$V_1\$ measures the voltage drop across the \$9.00 \ \Omega\$ resistor and has a reading of \$4.50 \ \text{V}\$.
> [image]

The reading on ammeter \$A_1\$ is \$I_1 = 0.50 \ \text{A}\$, and the reading on ammeter \$A_2\$ is \$I_2 = 0.38 \ \text{A}\$.

I am now trying to determine the unknown resistance \$R\$. It seems to me that we have two resistors in parallel here, so we can use the formula \$R_{\text{total}} = \dfrac{R_1 R_2}{ R_1 + R_2 }\$. So we have that \$R_{\text{total}} = \dfrac{R \times 4.0 \ \Omega}{ R + 4.0 \ \Omega }\$. We can now incorporate this into Ohm's law, where \$I = 0.38 \ \text{A}\$ and \$V = 6.0 \ \text{V} - 4.5 \ \text{V} = 1.5 \ \text{V}\$, so that we get \$1.5 = 0.38 \left( \dfrac{R \times 4.0 \ \Omega}{ R + 4.0 \ \Omega } \right) \ \Rightarrow R = 300 \ \Omega\$. But I am told that the solution is actually \$ I = 0.5 - 0.375 = 0.125 \ \text{A} \$ (where I round \$0.375\$ to \$0.38\$) and \$R = \dfrac{1.5}{0.125} = 12 \ \Omega\$. How is my reasoning incorrect, and what is the correct reasoning that leads to \$ I = 0.5 - 0.375 = 0.125 \ \text{A} \$ and \$R = \dfrac{1.5}{0.125} = 12 \ \Omega\$?

Comment: **I2** is not a total current (I2 flows only via 4ohms resistor ). Thus the **I_total = 0.5A** So **R_total = 1.5V/0.5A = 3Ohms**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating the reading on ammeter \$A_1\$: why am I incorrect?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/619345/calculating-the-reading-on-ammeter-a-1-why-am-i-incorrect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you do not see what path the current is taking in this circuit.
This may be handy
[image]

Comment: But aren't we suppose to consider conventional current (current travelling clockwise)?

Comment: @ThePointer No. Conventional current flows from higher (more positive) to lower potential.

Comment: @devnull Oops, yes, from the positive terminal of the battery to the negative terminal of the battery.

Comment: @ThePointer While you *can* do it the other way, you have to use negative signs everywhere, and it kinda turns into a mess.  It's much easier to do the math in the **positive** direction.